# Is there any reason for not to releasing an APK signed with debug key to the public?

Tags: android

I'm developing an open-source app for Android using Phonegap. The development reached the stage at which it's usable enough to release it to public (something like a beta version). I just want to put my current APK on Github. Is there any reason why I would not want to uploading the APK signed with debug key and signing it with release instead (and going through the hassle of making one etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

A debug key isn't any different from a normal key.  So there's no reason it would harm anything.  If you ever want to upgrade it, the upgrades will need to be signed with the same key or the user will have to uninstall first.  And if you ever upload to Google Play, the same key has to be used for all uploads there.  So make sure whatever key you release under is saved somewhere.

The only possible problem I see is that debug keys may have a short expiration date and need to be recreated (ADT used to expire them in 1 year).  So if you plan on maintaining it you may want to create a key with a longer expiration.

Comment: It's not possible to publish debug apk on Google Play.

Comment: Debug apk and debug key are different things

Answer (score 1):

You should create a key as there may be people who will be helping you in your current project and they will also be signing app, but with a different key and if they later upload apk to the GitHub, the user's will get different signature warning which will result of having to reinstall the app and thus losing any persisted data.

As long as you don't want anyone helping you out, it's fine the way it is.

You can use the one Android created for you if you are too lazy to create a new one. It is stored in `C:\Users\<your_user_name>\.android` assuming that you are using Windows as your OS.

Comment: I don't suggest releasing your key, of any type. They could then easily add any form of malware, and there's no way to differentiate your official apks from an illegitimate one

Answer (score 0):

No problem, you can just upload the release apk while making a new repo release on GitHub. I also do it, that way people who visit my repo can try the app then and there and it will be really helpful than uploading or hosting the apk somehwere else.

Also to make it easier to update the apk in future repo releases, I made a library which detects new repo release and downloads the latest apk. You can check out my library [here](https://github.com/supersu-man/GitHubAPKUpdater-Library#readme). Hope this will be useful to you as well.